# Simultaneous Controlling of image position via slider in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working with multiple images stored in 3D structure in MATLAB. In the first step, I have done the following implementation of slider for controlling of individual images stored in 3D structure:

```
b(:,:,1)=zeros(300,300);
b(:,:,2)=ones(300,300);
b(:,:,3)=zeros(300,300);
b(:,:,4)=ones(300,300);
b(:,:,5)=zeros(300,300);
smin=1;
smax=5;
hsl = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',smin,'Max',smax,...
                 'SliderStep',[1 1]./(smax-smin),'Value',1,...
                'Position',[20 20 200 20]);
set(hsl,'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata) imshow(b(:,:,round(get(hObject,'Value')))))
```

I would like to kindly ask you about implementation of slider controlling simultaneously of two subplots. I need to create a one figure containing of two subplots. The one slider will control both subplots simultaneously. Thank you very much in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the handles to each of your subplots:

```
allPlots = [subplot(121) subplot(122)];
```

Then simply modify your callback to call `imshow` for each subplot, passing that subplot's handle as the parent axes:

```
set(hsl,'Callback',@(hObject,~) arrayfun(@(thisPlot) imshow(b(:,:,round(get(hObject,'Value'))),'Parent',thisPlot),allPlots))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but I have one more related problem. I have two 3D structures stored in variables `a` and `b`. I again need to create one figure, with one slider, and two subplots (subplot(121), subplot(122)). Variable `a` shall be imagine in `subplot(121)`, and variable `b` shall be imagine in `subplot(122)`. Both variables will be controlled with one slider like it was in the previous case. Please, is there any way how to modify your proposed code to this task? Thank you very much.

Comment: To do multiple separate tasks in the callback for your slider just define the callback as a named function rather than an inline anonymous function. Then this callback can call `imshow` using the relevant variable on separate lines.

Comment: Please, can you show me MATLAB implementation? I am MATLAB beginner, and I am not able to make it, although it is not probably difficult. Thank you very much.